# Assigning a pointer to equal another pointer's value in c

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to set my pointer (numProcesses) equal to the command line argument entered in my program (it is an int value that gets stored in argv[1]).  My question is how do I get numProcess to equal argv[1] value.  Every time I try a different way of doing it, I get the address location of argv[1] instead of its content.  I know how pointers work for the most part.  I have no problem getting this to work in c++ but I am new to C so having a little bit of a rough time.  Below is my code and I appreciate any help/tips thank you.

```
 void parentInfo(int *numProcesses);



int main (int argc, int *argv[])
{
  //Creates a command line argument that stores an integer
  int *numProcesses = (int *)malloc(sizeof(12));

  if (argc < 2)
    {
      printf("\n\nUsage: %s <enter a number (12 or less)>\n\n", argv[0]);
      exit (-1);
    }
  else
    {
      numProcesses = argv[1];

      printf("numProcesses =  %d", numProcesses);

      if(*numProcesses > 12 || *numProcesses < 1)
        {
          printf("\n\nUsage: %s <enter a number (12 or lrss)>\n\n", argv[0]);
        }
      else
        {
          parentInfo(numProcesses);
        }


}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: How many `int`s can you fit in `sizeof(12)` bytes of memory?

Comment: This program doesn't type check. You treat `numProcesses` as `int*`, `char*`, and `int` within the space of 3 lines.  How would you implement this in c++??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `argv[1]` is a `char *`. There's no such thing as "`argv[1]`'s content" - `argv[1]` is a pointer to some location in the memory which (if we're lucky) contains a string.

What you actually need is a way to convert a string into a number. Well, there's `atoi`:

```
numProcesses = atoi(argv[1]);
```

Comment: ok thank you.  I though changing argv to int instead of char was wrong but i did it to see what happens.  That makes sense thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void parentInfo (int *numProcesses);

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int num = atoi (argv[1]);   // no error checking!
    parentInfo (&num);

    return 0;
}
```

Use `strtol` instead of `atoi` if you need error checking; which you probably would.